# Sales infos aggregation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a scenario where I got sales info in a table much like this:

*SalesTable* (ID,ID_Transct, Client, Product, Date, ...)

and I want to put thos sales into another tables wich are:

*DeliveryTable* (ID_Del, Client, Date, ...)

*DeliveryDetTable* (ID, ID_Del, Product, ...)

I want to do this in SQL-Server with a stored procedure that will be giving the argument ID_Transct (one ID_Transact can have many clients and products).

Anyone have any idea ? thanks in advance.

P.S. I am average with T-SQL

Comment: I can do it with C# / VB.NET but my boss want it to be in SQL side, and to be honest I dont have any experience with T-SQl to do such a stored procedure, I am trying to learn T-SQl for now but I am in a hurry for this one.

Comment: You will need two insert statements. One for DeliveryTable and one for DeliveryDetTable.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is how to figure out the ID_Del column (it is Identity on DeliveryTable)

Comment: scope_identity() perhaps?

Comment: Yes but the problem is my T-SQl (and SQl in general ) knowledge is so basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create procedure [dbo].[Sp_Test]
@ID_Transact int

As 
begin

insert into Table_2 (Date, Client)
select distinct Date, Client from Table_1 
where ID_Vente = @ID_Transact


insert into Table_2Det (ID_Del, Produit )
select Table_2 .ID_Del , Table_1 .Produit  from Table_1 inner join Table_2 on Table_1 .Client = Table_2 .Client 


end
GO
```